# How do I fix this error in VS Code with Python 3 and Anaconda?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, qt

How do I fix the error below, so I can open a `.jpg` image?

```
Warning: QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO is deprecated. Instead use:
   QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to enable platform plugin controlled per-screen factors.
   QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS to set per-screen factors.
   QT_SCALE_FACTOR to set the application global scale factor.
AxesImage(80,52.8;496x369.6)
```

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you need to use `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR`, `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` or `QT_SCALE_FACTOR` in place of `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO`. At a guess, it sounds like `QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS` might be worth a look first.

Comment: Yes, but where do I type these commands? What are the steps?                                               Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you would need to expand a fair amount on what you're actually doing in order to have a chance of this question being answered adequately. Especially if this isn't your own program/code. This is an (apparently) semi-common generic warning in Qt.

Comment: And FYI, if this is in Spyder, you aren't alone. But to reiterate, this error appears across Qt applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following commands in the shell before running the code. It will stop warnings.

`export QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO=0
export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
export QT_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTORS=1
export QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR", "1");` to set that `env` variable.
Make sure to very beginning may be just after the `int main()`